# Hole li sort by one dive with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating one bunch of li and I want to sort full li on the base of one date below is my code

please check my code given below.

```js
$(document).on('change','#exampleSelect',function(){
    var filter = $(this).val();
    if (filter == 'Newest') 
    {
     function parseDate(input) {
    var parts = input.match(/(\d+)/g);
    return new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5]); 
  }

  var elems = $.makeArray($(".dateDiv"));
  elems.sort(function(a, b) {
      return parseDate( $(a).text() ) < parseDate( $(b).text() ).find('.sorted_li').addClass('strike');
  });
  $(".past-exams").html(elems);​
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="exampleSelect" class="form-control">
 <option value="Newest">Newest</option>
 <option value="Oldest">Oldest</option>
 <option value="Best">Best</option>
 <option value="Worst">Worst</option>
</select>
<ul class="past-exams">
 <li class="sorted_li">
  <span class="grade grade-low">10%</span>
  <ul>
   <li class="dateDiv"><strong>Sep 24, 2019 05:06 AM</strong></li>
   <li><strong>Exam Time: </strong>00:00:19</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="sorted_li">
  <span class="grade grade-low">40%</span>
  <ul>
   <li class="dateDiv"><strong>Sep 17, 2019 12:58 AM</strong></li>
   <li><strong>Exam Time: </strong>00:00:15</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="sorted_li">
  <span class="grade grade-low">20%</span>
  <ul>
   <li class="dateDiv"><strong>Sep 17, 2019 12:13 AM</strong></li>
   <li><strong>Exam Time: </strong>00:03:18</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried to sort li with this jquery code but I am failed to do this.

can anybody help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few errors in your sorting logic, mainly in your `parseDate()` function:

```
function parseDate(input) {
    var parts = input.match(/(\d+)/g);
    return new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5]);
}
```

Breaking it down, firstly, look at the value of the `input` parameter:

```
"Sep 24, 2019 05:06 AM"
```

On this, you're calling `.match(/(\d+)/g)`, which returns the following:

```
var parts = input.match(/(\d+)/g); // [ "24", "2019", "05", "06" ]
```

As you can see the array contains *four* values. You then try to access elements in the array that don't exist:

```
return new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5]);
//                                                        ^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^
```

...which is the equivalent of:

```
return new Date("24", "2018", "05", "06", undefined, undefined);
```

Obviously that is not a valid date format, so your return value from `parseDate()` is `Invalid Date`.

Even if `parseDate()` returned a valid date, the main problem here is that you're trying to call the jQuery `.find()` method on the `Date` object:

```
elems.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseDate( $(a).text() ) < parseDate( $(b).text() ).find('.sorted_li').addClass('strike');
    //                                                        ^^^^^
});
```

---

#### Solution

A much simpler way to parse a date in your code would be to use the date string (`input`) as a `Date` parameter¹ ², like so:

```
var input = "Sep 24, 2019 05:06 AM";
var date  = new Date(input).getTime(); // returns number of milliseconds since "Unix Epoch"

console.log(date);
```

Using the above, you can compare the dates inside your `.sort()` loop like so:

```
elems.sort(function(a, b) {
    var dateA = new Date($(a).text()).getTime();
    var dateB = new Date($(b).text()).getTime();

    return dateA < dateB;
});
```

Putting it all together in an example (I've reformatted your code slightly for readability):

```js
$(document).on('change', '#exampleSelect', function() {
  var filter = $(this).val();

  if (filter == 'Newest') {
    var elems = $.makeArray($('.dateDiv'));

    elems.sort(function(a, b) {
      var dateA = new Date($(a).text()).getTime();
      var dateB = new Date($(b).text()).getTime();

      return dateA < dateB;
    });

    $('.past-exams').html(elems);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="exampleSelect" class="form-control">
  <option value="Newest">Newest</option>
  <option value="Oldest" selected>Oldest</option>
  <option value="Best">Best</option>
  <option value="Worst">Worst</option>
</select>
<ul class="past-exams">
  <li class="sorted_li">
    <span class="grade grade-low">10%</span>
    <ul>
      <li class="dateDiv"><strong>Sep 24, 2019 05:06 AM</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Exam Time: </strong>00:00:19</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sorted_li">
    <span class="grade grade-low">40%</span>
    <ul>
      <li class="dateDiv"><strong>Sep 17, 2019 12:58 AM</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Exam Time: </strong>00:00:15</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sorted_li">
    <span class="grade grade-low">20%</span>
    <ul>
      <li class="dateDiv"><strong>Sep 17, 2019 12:13 AM</strong></li>
      <li><strong>Exam Time: </strong>00:03:18</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

¹ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

² https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime

Comment: yes I tried this code but my problem is still as it id only .dateDiv is showing after script executing not Hole .sorted_li

Comment: there is nothing about class sorted_li in this code